# Do something when I clear an input

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script that whenever I type something in an input, a checkbox is checked.

So, I want to uncheck that checkbox when I delete all data in that input, with backspace, and do other actions too.

Edit:
I have multiple input and checkbox boxes. Some of you asked me for the code so this is it (They are multiple checkboxes and inputs in a table like this, all with different names):

```
<tr><td class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" name="has_mic" autocomplete="off">
&nbsp;Micr&oacute;fono</td>
<td class="txt"><input type="text" class="nsize upper" name="mic_obs"></td></tr>
```

And the script:

```
$("input[type=text]").keydown(
        function(){
            $(this).parent('.txt').siblings('.chk').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
        });
```

So, with this code, whenever I type in the input, the checkbox in the same <tr> is checked. What I want to do, is when I delete all that I typed, the checkbox gets unchecked and preform some other functions.

Comment: just add the "check" to your jquery that checks the checkbox, `if (input.val().trim().length == 0) //uncheck checkbox`

Comment: You should always provide relevant code/HTML markup. Have you got only one input and one checkbox???

Comment: I just edited my question, there's all that you asked for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('input[type=text]').on('input', function () {
    if(this.value)
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true)
    else
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="checkbox"/>
```